# .Net Core 1.1.0 Visual Studio Tooling

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-core, .net-core

I've just migrated a asp.net core project from 1.0.1 to 1.1.0 and when running `dotnet run` or `dotnet restore` I get the following message

```
C:\Users\you\Desktop\API\src\API\API.xproj(7,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\1.0.0-preview4-004110\Extensions\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
```

I've installed all the SDK and runtimes, but still can't neither create .Net Core 1.1.0 projects in visual studio nor restore in console my packages.

[image]

The `project.json` is as follows, supposedly the migration is right, but still can't figure it out.

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "dependencies": {
       "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.1.0",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Business.Handlers": "1.0.0-*",
    "Business.Connectors": "1.0.0-*",
    "Common": "1.0.0-*",
    "DataAccessLayer": "1.0.0-*"
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.1": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "Views",
      "Areas/**/Views",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

Comment: update your packages to use the 1.1.0 version too. For example: from `"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.1",` to `"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.1.0",`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was in the `global.json` of my solution the version property, I had it changed to `1.0.0-preview2-1-003177` and it worked.

```
{
  "projects": [ "src", "test" ],
  "sdk": {
    "version": "1.0.0-preview2-1-003177" //Previously 1.0.0-preview2-003131
  }
}
```

Comment: you mean tools?

Comment: No, in the solution directory there is a `global.json` there it has the .Net release in a property `version`.

Comment: @J._Pichardo, is it related? http://www.hanselman.com/blog/PublishingASPNETCore11ApplicationsToAzureUsingGitDeploy.aspx

Comment: Yeah, that was exactly my problem and the solution. I didn't see it.

Comment: it was published just today

Comment: Ohh, that is why. :p

Answer (score 0):

You need to download .NET Core 1.1 SDK - Installer from Microsoft website. If you can download only runtime as well. Below is the url for the same.

https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/core

Please see image below for more details.

[.net core 1.1.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Foxd.png)

Regards,
Sachin Pawar

Comment: Thanks @Sachin but I'd already done that, the answer Is above, also there Is a link to Scott Hanselman's blog solving the same issue.